# Vee-validate - show error if input does not return an object

Tags: vue.js, vee-validate

I'm using Vee-validate in my Vue.js project, where in the purchase flow I have an input where I write a postal code and a list of Dealers show appear if they serve the postal code.

However, and my question, is there a way for vee-validate to check if there are **no dealers associated to that postal code**? So that the user knows to write up another postal code until they can find a dealer.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Just write a custom validator?

Comment: But how can I send the object Dealers to the vee-validate validator?